# Compute  as a random sum (Monte Carlo)

Tags: python, python-3.x, montecarlo, pi

I need to estimate the value of pi by evaluating the sum 
 = (1 / ( + 1)) ∑ 1/( 1 −  2 )^ (1 / 2) where  are uniformly distributed random numbers.

```
import math
import random

def Pi(N,x):
     S = (1/(N+1))*(1/(1-x**2)**(0.5))
     return S

def function(N,a,b):
     x = random.uniform(a,b)
     total = sum(Pi(N,x))
     return total

print(function(1000,0.0,1.0))
```

The output is basically giving me this.

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: What part is throwing the error?

Comment: Sorry I did not include the output. I keep getting "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" and I honestly don't know what i means. I will take a look at the link you just put.

Comment: print(function(1000.0))
S = sum(Pi(N,0.0,1.0))

Comment: You've mistyped the error message. When I run your code, I get `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`. Not being iterable is very different than "cannot be interpreted as an integer". In the future, please copy the whole exception traceback into your question, to avoid this sort of issue. It will also show exactly which line is causing the exception.

Comment: `Pi(N,x)` returns a number, where `sum()` expects a list of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `sum` on the result of `Pi`. But `Pi` returns a number, not an iterable. Just remove the call to `sum`. [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) takes an iterable (list, dictionary, tuple, etc) and adds all the values together. So when you pass it something it can't iterate over (like a floating point number), it can't sum anything, because there's no values to iterate over.

```
import random

def Pi(N,x):
     S = (1/(N+1))*(1 / (1-x**2) ** 0.5)
     return S

def function(N,a,b):
     x = random.uniform(a,b)
     total = Pi(N,x)
     return total

print(function(1000,0.0,1.0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you want to be running the `Pi` function `N` times, not just once. For this you'll need a loop of some sort. Since you want to use the builtin `sum`, a generator expression would be very natural:

```
def function(N, a, b):
    total = sum(Pi(N, random.uniform(a, b)) for _ in range(N))
    return total
```

This doesn't return anything too close to `pi` though. Maybe it's `pi/2`? I don't know how your formula is supposed to work well enough to spot the issue with the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually sampling pi/2, and you don'rt really need the `N` in the `Pi` function. You should apply it at the end, after summation

```
import math
import random

def Pi(x):
    return 1.0/math.sqrt(1.0 - x*x)

random.seed(12345)

N = 100000
total = sum(Pi(random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)) for _ in range(N))

total /= float(N+1)

print(2.0*total)
```

will produce

```
3.1429294210892524
```